# Who owns the the lake?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

In the U.S. if I anchor my houseboat for an extended period in the middle of a large lake connected to a navigable waterway can the city or municipality bordering the lake charge me taxes?

Comment: In Nevada it seems that houseboats don't pay taxes http://finance.zacks.com/pay-property-tax-live-houseboat-nevada-3860.html

Answer (score 2):

Property tax? No. Every other tax, like sales tax or income tax if you get a job, yes.

Comment: I've never heard of a city/municipality charging income tax...

Comment: @sharur good point. I suppose I didn't really answer the question then!